# unwrapKey function with AES-KW not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, internet-explorer-11, webcrypto-api

On MS Edge following unwrapping code works:

```
window.crypto.subtle.unwrapKey(
                                "raw",
                                wrappedKey,
                                derivedKey,
                                { "name": "AES-KW", iv: iv },
                                { "name": "AES-CBC", iv: iv },
                                false,
                                ["decrypt"]
                            )
```

The IE11 implementation is based on a unfinished version of the W3C WebCrypto APIs, there is a [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn302335(v=vs.85).aspx) but there isn't any example code available and my tries have not worked so far. Following does not throw an error on IE11 but the resulting key is null:

```
window.msCrypto.subtle.unwrapKey(
                                    wrappedKey,                                        
                                    {
                                        "name": "AES-KW",
                                        iv: iv
                                    },
                                    e.target.result,
                                    false,
                                    ["decrypt"]
                                )
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qayxswedcvfr/j4stmhLo/7/)  that you can run.

Comment: So just as ref... I am getting an error in both Edge and IE11,  It looks like they were being swallowed.  I am guessing this isn't your full implementation.  Can you isolate a subset of what exactly isn't working?  I get StringToArrayBuffer is not a function in Edge.  In IE11 I get you are setting oncomplete on undefined.

Comment: I updated the code, StringToArrayBuffer is not needed in IE11 only in others browsers, otherwise the code is complete for testing purporses.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a shim, like [webcrypto-shim](https://github.com/vibornoff/webcrypto-shim) to fix the incomplete implementation of IE11

Comment: You mean to workaround it, yes, we did that, but this affects the performance of the solution among other consequences.

Comment: Sure, but I don't think you can aim for anything better than that on the IE11 front ...